# How to receive and parse xml request from external url that ends with .dll

Tags: php, xml, api

I am new to apis and xml requests but learning. I have been given a task to receive test xml data from an external url.

I can do a simple test as below to get me going, which works fine. When I use the actual url and try to do the same I get nothing back at all. I have enabled 'allow_url_fopen = On' and have curl enabled too in case.

This works

```
$xmldata = simplexml_load_file("https://tecadmin.net/employees.xml") or die("Failed to load");

foreach($xmldata->children() as $empl) {         
 echo $empl->firstname . ", ";     
 echo $empl->lastname . ", ";     

}
```

The actual url I am connecting to ends with .dll like below - maybe this is the problem. I can view the actual results no problem in my browser.

```
http://ipaddress/folder/Search.dll?page=Search&depart=EDB&countryid=1
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction pls?

Comment: The URL makes no difference to anything.

Comment: ok all helps tks

Comment: You should review the output of the url with curl like this:  `curl -s http://ipaddress/folder/Search.dll?page=Search&depart=EDB&countryid=1` to make sure you are getting XML back.  Perhaps you can pipe the results to xmllint just to make sure that the XML coming back is valid like this:  `curl url | xmllint --format -` .  Lastly, make sure that the XML has the structure you expect.